# Adding uninstall information with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, addremoveprograms

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer for my program but I want to be able to add an icon and change some of the information displayed in the Control Panel (Add/Remove Programs).

I know that Inno Setup adds a registry key to get the program listed in the first place so I wondered if this could be extended in any way so that, at the least, my icon is displayed in the list!

Comment: If I get it right you meant how to change the icon and display name in the Add/Remove program list, but what is the third information ? What did you meant with the *change some of thre inform displayed in the Control Panel* ?

Comment: As you'll guess, you are right about the icon and display name. What you quoted was a typo but see my comment on your answer to see what I meant!

Comment: Ok; anyway you may find also these directives interesting: [`AppComments`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appcomments.htm), [`AppContact`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appcontact.htm), [`AppPublisher`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_apppublisher.htm), [`AppPublisherURL`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_apppublisherurl.htm), [`AppSupportPhone`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appsupportphone.htm), [`AppSupportURL`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appsupporturl.htm) and...

Comment: ...[`AppUpdatesURL`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appupdatesurl.htm). So as the *plain old website* might act the [`AppPublisherURL`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_apppublisherurl.htm), but it's just my guess :-)

Comment: Ah - I don't know why I didn't see the `AppSupportURL` and the `AppUpdatesURL` in the script I have. Thanks again - very helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change the icon displayed in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet program list specify the  [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) directive in the [`[Setup]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupsection) section.

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\Application.exe
```

If you want to specify a custom name for the program's entry in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet then specify the [`UninstallDisplayName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname) directive also in the [`[Setup]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupsection) section.

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayName=Custom name shown in Add/Remove Programs applet
```

Comment: Thanks TLama, that is exactly what I wanted. It works perfectly. The only other thing that I wouldn't mind changing but it's not too important is the web links in the uninstall information. I don't really need the 'Support Link' or the 'Update Information' website. Just a plain old 'website' would be good

Comment: You don't have that much control over the Add/Remove applet. You're limited by what Windows offers to show.