# Updating version number in Add/Remove programs window

Tags: windows, version, inno-setup

We have an application consisting of various parts:

1. A printer driver build with Inno-Setup.
2. Custom written C# dll's.
3. An AutoIt script, packaging and installing the previous two.

The printer driver is listed in the Add/Remove section of Windows, with `[name]`, `[publisher]` and `[installed on]` fields displayed as expected. But the `[size]` and `[version]` fields are left blank.

Our client wants us to update the `[version]` field. Where is this information stored (how to update or add this in the Add/Remove section of Windows)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several properties under `[Setup]` that control version numbers:

```
VersionInfoVersion=
VersionInfoTextVersion=
AppVersion=
```

The field important for the question is `AppVersion` directive, which InnoSetup writes into the `DisplayVersion` registry key.

A complete sample can be found [here](https://github.com/lextm/ActionListWinForms/blob/master/setup.iss).

Comment: Well, I can't say nothing against facts; there are really several directives (not properties) that controls version numbers in `[Setup]` section but sorry, this answer doesn't explain anything. Which one of those you've listed should OP use ? From that complete sample it's also impossible to understand which directive is for. I'm not a downvoter, so I'm leaving this without voting... Maybe I'll come back with an upvote if there will be some explanation here :-)

Comment: A well-written installer should have all three directives/properties set. Missing any of them will lead to a bad installer IMHO. To learn more about each of them, Inno Setup help can be checked. @TLama

Comment: @LexLi, you didn't get my point. Your answer is useless, not wrong. It's like when you'd ask me how to cook sweet and sour pork and I'll tell you: "There are several ingredients but look, I have one mess with me." You'll be probably able to find out what was it cooked from, but do you consider my answer useful ? Even worse is your answer: "There are several properties", and what ? Look at my "complete sample", of what ? What your sample even does except it uses those three directives you mentioned ? How in the world will I get from it which directive does what ?

Comment: @LexLi, I hope I know what well written installer should have (and wouldn't call it bad if doesn't) as well as where to find the information, but will this find also the reader of your post ? I'm afraid not and thus I'm giving you my historicaly second downvote (the first post was deleted by owner, so I couldn't take it back) and because as a downvote hint says "this answer is not useful". Couldn't you just point to the help and/or take quotas from there, something [`like this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11593471/960757) ?

Comment: besides of the comment from @TLama I cannot see how this explains how to UPDATE the version information

Comment: @MarcoRebsamen the sample contains the script to do that.

Comment: @LexLi at which line? It sets the version information but if you have an installer that is an update to an existing installation InnoSetup does not update the version information AFAIK. As the others below stated you need to change that yourself in the Registry.

Answer (score 5):

Check this section

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

You can choose your application by GUID of it and you can manipulate its data
there are DisplayVersion key to show the version and an actual version key for other than display usages , and there is a size field that you can add your program size there

Answer (score 2):

It's the 'DisplayVersion' value in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ApplicationName
```

*'ApplicationName' being replaced with your actual Application Name obviously*

*ApplicationName* may also be a GUID instead, if you didn't configure one.

Inno-Setup should have the ability to change this.